# Как установить пакет с автодополнением в Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

хочу установить пакет с автодополнеием для Anaconda, зашел на этот github https://github.com/Jupyter-contrib/jupyter_nbextensions_configurator, там написано, что все просто, нужно лишь вставить эту строку conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator, но куда ее вставлять? Пытался и в командную строку не вышло и в самом блоке Anaconda - тоже, помогите пожалуйста разобраться